# Display default notification in onMessageReceived

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging for Android. When my app is in the foreground, FCM will invoke `onMessageReceived` on my app's `FirebaseMessagingService` subclass.

When my app is in the background, the Android OS will create a default notification entry in the system tray. That notification entry looks pretty good to me; for the notifications I need to send, I don't particularly need to interrupt the user with the notification. The default notification in the system tray is just fine.

My question is, how do I make that "default" notification happen in `onMessageReceived` when my app is in the foreground? Is there a way to say, "I don't need to intercept this notification; please just do what you'd normally do if I were in the background"?

(Do I have to simulate it by hand with `NotificationCompat.Builder`? If so, which settings do I need to pass to get default behavior?)

Answer (score 0):

When the app is in the background, your notifications are processed by the Google Services, which takes care of displaying your notifications as required, including the default click action (opening the app) and the notification icon.

When the app is in the foreground, the received messages are processed by the app.

Yes, you will have to mimic the NotificationCompat.Builder to look like default. There is no other way to do this without intercepting with onMessageReceived() callback.

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive